# Firebase database rules. Как разрешить добавлять новые данные, но не изменять существующие?

Tags: firebase-database, rules

Мне необходимы правила для *Firebase database*, чтобы пользователи могли создавать новые данные, но не могли их редактировать.
Я пытался использовать для этого проверку *newData*:

```
 "rules":
{
 "Game":
{ 
 "players":
  {
    ".write":"newData.child('тут 
   может быть любое значение').child('Find').val() === 'false'"
  }
 }
}
```

На самом деле мне просто нужно проверить есть ли данный пользователь в базе данных, но без использования аутентификации.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что правильным вариантом будет использовать data и newData и делать проверку на наявность т.е.

```
"rules":
{
 "Game":
{ 
 "players":
  {
    "$player":
   {
    ".write":"!data.exists() && !newData.exists()
   }
  }
 }
}
```

При этом !data.exists() будет проверять наявность данных в базе, а !newData.exists() это что-то вроде проверки на удаление.